# I don't know how to loop? loop until str.contains(orderIds, '2') == true or after 3 Bars then strategy.cancel

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have been trying all day but can't get the loop to properly run...

I need it to:
strategy.exit when the order has been filled, by using orderIDs to see if position is open
and to strategy.cancel after 3 bars if it is not filled, by using OrderIDs to see if position is open

```
var line[] imbalancedUpMidLines = array.new_line()
var line[] imbalancedUpMidLines2 = array.new_line()


orderIds = ""

for idx = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    strSuffix = idx == strategy.opentrades - 1 ? "" : ", "
    orderIds += strategy.opentrades.entry_id(idx) + strSuffix

//Show result on the chart
label.new(bar_index, high, orderIds)



if entry_signal_all
    if str.contains(orderIds, '1') == false
        array.push(imbalancedUpMidLines, line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=high, x2=bar_index+20, y2=high, extend=extend.right, color = color.red))
        strategy.order(id = '1', direction= strategy.long, qty = 0.1, limit = atrBandBot)
        line1=line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=high, x2=bar_index+20, y2=high, extend=extend.right, color = color.red)
        i = 1    
        while str.contains(orderIds, '1') == true  
            if i >= 3
                strategy.cancel('1')
                break
            else
                i += 1
        strategy.exit(id = "C1", from_entry= '1', limit=line.get_y1(line1)) 


    else       
        if str.contains(orderIds, '2') == false
            array.push(imbalancedUpMidLines2, line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=high, x2=bar_index+20, y2=high, extend=extend.right, color = color.red))
            strategy.order(id = '2', direction= strategy.long, qty = 0.1, limit = atrBandBot)
            line2=line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=high, x2=bar_index+20, y2=high, extend=extend.right, color = color.red)
            i = 1    
            while str.contains(orderIds, '2') == true  
                if i >= 3
                    strategy.cancel('2')
                    break
                else
                    i += 1
                strategy.exit(id = "C2", from_entry= '2', limit=line.get_y1(line2))
```

i also tried this loop but i have no clue

```
            i = 1    
            while i >= 3  
                if str.contains(orderIds, '2')
                    strategy.exit(id = "C2", from_entry= '2', limit=line.get_y1(line2))
                    break
                else if i <= 3
                    strategy.cancel('2')
                    break
                else
                    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably because the loop is in an if statement that doesn't always happen

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).